# Loop stopping when undefined

Tags: json, jquery, jsonp, yql

**UPDATE 6:**

Based on the `console.log`, I have noticed that some of the objects have:

```
thumbnail: Array[2]
```

Others have:

```
thumbnail: Object
```

and others don't have it at all.

So it seems that what @Felix Kling could be true.

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%20%3D%20%22http%3A%2F%2Ffeeds.bbci.co.uk%2Fnews%2Frss.xml%22&format=json&callback=cbfunc
```

if you can't access the link, try:

```
http://pastebin.com/T4GPQvtk
```

---

**UPDATE 5:**

I am still getting url as undefined with:

```
for (var i = 0; i < news.length; i++) {
    news[i].thumbnail = ( $.isArray( news[i].thumbnail ) ) ? news[i].thumbnail : [news[i].thumbnail];

    buildHTML.push( "<a href='" + news[i].thumbnail[0].url + "' target='_blank'>" + news[i].title + "</a><br />" + news[i].pubDate );
}
```

---

**UPDATE 4:**

The following:

```
buildHTML.push( "<a href='" + news[i].thumbnail[0] ? news[i].thumbnail[0].url : $.isArray( news[i].thumbnail ) + "' target='_blank'>" + news[i].title + "</a><br />" + news[i].pubDate );
```

gives me:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined
```

---

**UPDATE 3:**

The following does not seem to work either:

```
buildHTML.push( "<a href='" + news[i].thumbnail[0] ? news[i].thumbnail[0].url : news[i].thumbnail.url + "' target='_blank'>" + news[i].title + "</a><br />" + news[i].pubDate );
```

The error I get is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined
```

---

**UPDATE 2:**

The following does not seem to work:

```
buildHTML.push( "<a href='" + news[i].thumbnail=$.isArray(news[i].thumbnail)?news[i].thumbnail:[news[i].thumbnail] + "' target='_blank'>" + news[i].title + "</a><br />" + news[i].pubDate );
```

The error I get is:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
$.ajax.successyql_news_widget.js:25
bjquery-1.4.2.min.js:124
c.extend.ajax.Ajquery-1.4.2.min.js:125
(anonymous function)yql:1
```

---

**UPDATE 1:**

The problem happens, when I add the image to push as follows:

```
buildHTML.push( "<img src='" + news[i].thumbnail[0].url + "' /><a href='" + news[i].link + "' target='_blank'>" + news[i].title + "</a><br />" + news[i].pubDate );
```

---

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

From the following url:

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%20%3D%20%22http%3A%2F%2Ffeeds.bbci.co.uk%2Fnews%2Frss.xml%22&format=json&callback=cbfunc
```

I am trying to capture the data via a look like this:

```
function get_news() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%20%3D%20%22http%3A%2F%2Ffeeds.bbci.co.uk%2Fnews%2Frss.xml%22&format=json&callback=cbfunc&rand=" + Math.random(),
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'callback',
        jsonpCallback: 'cbfunc',
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        },
        success: function(data) { 

            var buildHTML = [];

            var news = data.query.results.rss.channel.item;

            for (var i = 0; i < news.length; i++) {
                buildHTML.push( "<a href='" + news[i].link + "' target='_blank'>" + news[i].title + "</a><br />" + news[i].pubDate );
            }

            $('.portlet-content').empty().append(buildHTML.join("<br /><br />"))

        }

    });

}
```

This works fine as long as the thumbnail section looks like this:

```
"thumbnail": [
{
    "height": "49",
    "url": "http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/48915000/jpg/_48915868_48915872.jpg",
    "width": "66"
}
{
    "height": "81",
    "url": "http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/52468000/jpg/_52468689_48915872.jpg",
    "width": "144"
}
]
```

However, when the thumbnail section looks like this:

```
"thumbnail": {
    "height": "81",
    "url": "http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/53705000/jpg/_53705922_012314461-1.jpg",
    "width": "144"
}
```

I get an error "undefined", the loop stops and I get nothing on the screen.

How do I ignore those, and continue the script without it stopping on the error?

Comment: No where in your code are you even referencing the thumbnails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, you seem to want this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < news.length; i++) {
    var item = news[i];

    if($.isArray(item.thumbnail)) {
        var size = +item.thumbnail[0].width * +item.thumbnail[0].height,
            selected = 0;
        for(var j = 1, jl = item.thumbnail.length; j < jl; j++) {
            var t_size = +item.thumbnail[j].width * +item.thumbnail[j].height;
            if(t_size < size) {
                size = t_size;
                selected = j;
            }
        }
        buildHMTL.push("<img src='" + news[i].thumbnail[selected].url + "' />");
    }
    buildHTML.push( "<a href='" + item.link + "' target='_blank'>" + item.title + "</a><br />" + item.pubDate );
}
```

Comment: This works almost perfectly.  However, it should not be returning the larger image, only the small image if it exists.  The jsonp includes the image resolutions, so how would I use those to only get the smaller image if it exists? i.e. if you look at the original question before the updates, you will see the width and heights.  only the smaller image is needed.

Comment: @oshirowanen: Please see my update. This works under the assumption that there could be more than two thumbnails. If there are always only two at max, then you can compare them directly, without the loop.

Comment: Nevermind, got the if statement for the image resolution working.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @oshirowanen: Next time, you should state clearly what you want. Finding this stuff out through questions and comments is cumbersome.

Answer (score 3):

You may create an array if the json matches the 2nd example(isn't an array yet):

```
news[i].thumbnail=($.isArray(news[i].thumbnail))
                   ? news[i].thumbnail
                   : [news[i].thumbnail];
```

Comment: How do I check if the json matches the 2nd statement, before using your script?

Comment: $.isArray inside my code already makes the check(will be false given the 2nd example)

Comment: @oshirowanen: You have to to this beforehand, not inside the string concatenation. I.e. inside the loop before you call `buildHTML.push`. And then use `news[i].thumbnail[0].url` to get the URL.

Comment: @oshirowanen: Could it be that not every entry has `thumbnail`? That would be the only explanation. And please don't just try things without thinking. Of course your update 4 will not work even if it would not give you that error. It just clutters your question.

Comment: @Felix Kling, That is a possibility, but at the moment, this link `http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%20%3D%20%22http%3A%2F%2Ffeeds.bbci.co.uk%2Fnews%2Frss.xml%22&format=json&callback=cbfunc` seems to have some sort of thumbnail section for all sections.

Comment: @oshirowanen: The link does not work for me. Maybe you can post a dump of the JSON response somewhere (http://pastebin.com/).

Comment: @Felix Kling, seems you were right, some of the objects don't seem to have a thumbnail section at all based on the console.log.  How do I get around this?

Comment: *and others don't have it at all.* That's your problem. What do you want to do if it contains no thumbnail?

Comment: @Felix Kling, I only want it to display the thumbnails if the smaller version exists, if only the large verion exists, I do not want to display that next to the links, and if no thumbnail exists, then just display the links.

Comment: @oshirowanen: Please have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add [] brackets to cast "thumbnail" from object to array.

`"thumbnail": [ {
    "height": "81",
    "url": "http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/53705000/jpg/_53705922_012314461-1.jpg",
    "width": "144"
}]`

will work

Comment: I don't have any control over how the jsonp is generated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Try catch](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_try_catch.asp) or a simple IF before the code to check to see if the code is in the format you want before attempting to manipulate it. The issue seems to be that if your thumbnails 'array' is only one object its not sent as an array. A simple if check could stop this issue your having.

you can use a conditional operator which would go something like this:

```
buildHTML.push( "<img src='" + news[i].thumbnail[0] ? news[i].thumbnail[0].url : news[i].thumbnail.url + "' /><a href='" + news[i].link + "' target='_blank'>" + news[i].title + "</a><br />" + news[i].pubDate );
```

**UPDATE**
this conditional expression will find the URL or it will just return "". I didn't see that some items have no URL which is why my first suggestion didn't work. Use this expression for getting your url

```
news[i].thumbnail ? news[i].thumbnail[0] ? news[i].thumbnail[0].url : news[i].thumbnail.url : ''
```

Comment: I have been trying the if method, but am not sure how to write it.

Comment: Could you please do a console.log(news[i]) and post what you find? Also is there a live version of this anywhere?

Comment: @Decad, I am now getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`.

Comment: Odd, see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rzcbw/14/ - its just the URL part and if you check your console there is no errors